# Rsync large dir, bigger than destination, need to stop and start

Tags: rsync

I have an Ubuntu server with 4TB storage. Most of it is taken up by one dir. I was told the dir was about 1.5TB, so I attached a 2TB drive on USB, and started a rsync -arW inn tmux to copy it over. Now I have figured out it is about 3.6TB. I have the USB drive on /dev/sdb1. If CTRL Z that rsync, swap out the 2TB drive for another, will it start back up? Or do I have to copy the data already there to, say a 4TB drive, swap that into the enclosure on sdb1, and restart.

Answer (score 2):

That approach won't work. However if you leave the first disk plugged in and stop the transfer (or just wait for it to terminate when the disk is full), then plug in a another drive and mount that (without removing or unmounting the first), you can use the `--compare-dest` option for `rsync` to avoid copying anything to the new disk that wasn't copied to the first. Eg, the second command could be something like:

```
rsync -aW --compare-dest=/path/to/original/mount /path/to/source /path/to/new/mount
```

The `man` page snippet for `--compare-dest`:

> This option instructs rsync to use DIR on the destination machine as an additional hierarchy to compare destination files against doing transfers (if the files are missing
>                 in the destination directory).  If a file is found in DIR that is identical to the sender’s file, the file will NOT be transferred to the destination directory.   This  is
>                 useful  for creating a sparse backup of just files that have changed from an earlier backup.  This option is typically used to copy into an empty (or newly created) directory.
>
> If DIR is a relative path, it is relative to the destination directory.  See also --copy-dest and --link-dest.

Comment: I will try this as soon as the first one pops